# How to install application as windows service using NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have written nsis script for my java project. I have successfully created a exe file using this nsis script. Final step of my installation process is installing my application as windows service using a batch file. I have installed successfully through command line using following code

```
"c:\program Files\program Files\test\bin\prunsrv.exe" //IS//servicename --Startup=auto --Jvm="Auto" --Classpath="%CLASSPATH%" --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=com.class.name  --StartParams start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=com.class.name --StopParams stop
```

same commands I have executed through nsis script is not working well. I have tried the following code

```
Exec '"$INSTDIR\bin\prunsrv.exe" //IS//servicename --Startup=auto --Jvm="Auto" --Classpath="%CLASSPATH%" --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=com.class.name  --StartParams start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=com.class.name --StopParams stop'
```

$INSTDIR refer to this directory c:\program Files\test.

Comment: And the problem is what exactly? Is the service installed partially or not at all? Wrong configuration?

Comment: The problem is the application is not installed as windows servcie when i running nsis script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExpandEnvStrings to expand %classpath% before the exec...

Comment: How to use ExpandEnvStrings to my command? I have tried        ExpandEnvString $0 %CLASSPATH%                                  Exec '"$INSTDIR\bin\prunsrv.exe" //IS//servicename --Startup=auto --Jvm="Auto" --Classpath="$0" --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=com.class.name  --StartParams start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=com.class.name --StopParams stop' 
But this is not working

Comment: It looks OK to me, try comparing NSIS and the working batchfile executions with Process Monitor...